# Problem with font in markdown-mode table

Tags: font-lock, text-properties, markdown-mode

I am using variable-pitch for markdown-mode. Tables use fixed-pitch `(markdown-table-face)`. The table aligns for regular text. It breaks alignment for links. The spaces are also underlined.

[image: screenshot]

Considering a link `[foo](bar)`, the first part - `[foo]` - shows text properties face as `(markdown-table-face and markdown-link-face)`. This part renders as fixed-pitch. The next part - `(bar)` - shows text properties face as `markdown-url-face`. This part renders as variable-pitch.

I think if we can prepend `markdown-table-face` to the text properties list of the `(bar)` then it would render correctly?  How can I do that?  Or is there any other means to achieve this?

Comment: Don't URLs kind of ask for fixed pitch even when inline? I suggest just customizing `markdown-url-face` to a fixed pitch face and moving on.